# ruby on rails 4 activerecord - combine and unique joins query optimization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, join, activerecord

I am trying to figure out if this activerecord query is good or should there be a better optimization for this ?

I need to combine 3 queries and make sure the results is unique. I am using .uniq

```
ads1 = Advertisement.where(city: property.city, state: property.state, country_id: property.address_country_id)
ads2 = Advertisement.where(city: nil, state: property.state, country_id: property.address_country_id)
ads3 = Advertisement.where(city: nil, state: nil, country_id: property.address_country_id)

combine_ads = ads1 + ads2 + ads3
uniq_ads = combine_ads.uniq { |ads| ads.id}
uniq_ads = uniq_ads.sort_by { |ads| ads.created_at}
final_ads = uniq_ads.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => params[:page_limit])
status 200
present final_ads, with: Api::Presenters::AdvertisementDetail
```

I am using ruby on rails 4

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
```

Can you review the above activerecords combined unique join and maybe provide feedback if its good or there is a better optimization way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `combine_ads` to:

```
combine_ads = Advertisement.where(city: [property.city, nil], 
                                  state: [property.state, nil], 
                                  country_id: property.address_country_id)
                           .order('created_at asc')
```

Only extra case in above is, it will also have those rows, where `city` is `property.city`, but `state` is `nil`, which your breakdown doesn't track.

You wouldn't need to `uniq_ads` either, we are already ordering with `created_at`.